# how to solve compile error "cannot resolve reference project with such signature"?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using IntelliJ 15.0.2, Play FrameWork 2.4, SBT 0.13.8, Java 1.8, Scala-sdk-2.117

This only one compile error, here is code

[image]
[image]
[image]

I guess problem is IDE compile error and importing error, but I don't know solution

Comment: Please give text, not screenshots.

Comment: Type mismatch expected : (Request[AnyContent]) => Result, actual : (Request[AnyContent])=> Any

Comment: Type mismatch expected : BodyParser[NotInferedA], acural : (Request[AnyContent]) => Any

Comment: Don't put important information in comments - edit the question and delete the comments.

Comment: Type mismatch expected :Result, actual:(Request[AnyContent])=> Any

Comment: i'm sovled it! Compile OK Build OK ,, Just IntellJ showing error but Not real error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `Redirect` should be:

```
Redirect(routes.Admin.project(), SEE_OTHER)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just Intellj showing error , error when routes filie in Int Value is minus. ex.) GET /admin/project        controller.Admin.project(A:Int ?=1, B:Int ?=0, C:Int ?= -1) ,,/////,,, case Intellij 'C' is show error